# Pay Now on Dashboard - too many redirects

Tags: user-dashboard

Not sure what the issue is - but if someone tries to pay an unpaid registration for an event or membership - or incomplete contribution - we get the issue of too many redirects. I have posted about this before - the issue was the contribution page was disabled or no longer there - but this time - the contribution page is active.

Here is an example of how a link is being parsed: (### are numbers)

https://org.org/membership/member-dashboard/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&page=CiviCRM&reset=1&id=&ccid=###&cs=&cid=###

Looks like the page ID is missing - but I could be reading this wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you update the setting to set the contribution page to use for 'Pay now' pending contribution?

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Settings. Select contribution page for 'Default invoice payment page' field and save the form.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Should the default just be a basic donation page?  Right now its setup for membership.

Comment: What version of Civi are you using and did you resave the setting?

Comment: 5.16.2 and yes. re-saving it fixed it - thanks! We changed it from the membership donation page to the regular donation page - this made more sense.

Comment: This worked for me, although our issue was a little different. We were getting "too many redirects" in more of a random fashion from a Wordpress page with our contribution page inserted via shortcode. After reading Pradeep's answer, I just ensured that the Default invoice payment page matched our contribution page, which is the main donation page on our site. It was set to ANOTHER contribution page which was enabled, so I'm not sure why this worked. We are running Wordpress 5.2.3 with Civi 5.12.4, but got "too many redirects" when I tried upgrading to Civi 5.18.4 and so reverted to a backup.

Comment: I also should add that our mismatched "Default invoice payment page" was a pure Donation page (no Membership) but it was setup for a campaign which has since ended. I find it very weird that "too many redirects" happened on some occasions only and even for me doing live tests to help diagnose. I am hoping that this will allow us to finally upgrade to CiviCRM 5.18.4, where the primary stumbling block previously was due to a theme conflict with CiviCRM's Clean URL's feature (added in 5.13.0)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem of totally random (it appears) "too many redirects." We ARE running WordPress 5.2.4 with Civi 5.18.4 now and many contributions go through. We only get "too many redirects" at time upon pressing "Confirm contribution."